# how to sum elements of array using different way

Tags: matlab, loops, optimization

i know one simple way to sum elements of array is following code

```
sum=0;
>> a=[12 31,45,10];
>> n=length(a);
>> for i=1:n
sum=sum+a(i);
end
>> sum

sum =

    98
```

also there  is another way to do it ,like this one

```
>> sum=0;
>> for a=[10 21 23 45]
sum=sum+a;
end
>> sum

sum =

    99
```

i want to know which one faster and why,maybe second one is equivalent of pointer in c++?please help me

Comment: what about sum(a)? -> dont use "sum" as a name for a variable, it is the name of the sum-function!

Comment: Note that the top result on google for `matlab how to sum elements of array` leads you to the [solution](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/sum.html) directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use:

```
a = [10 21 23 45];
yourSum = sum(a);
```

To answer your question further: check your results using `tic` and `toc`